# token has expired in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, refresh-token

I have this server code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const sslOptions = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, "private/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem")
    ),
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  };
  
  const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    ssl: sslOptions,
  });

  db.getConnection(function(err, conn){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
  });

const generateAccessToken = (user) => {
    return jwt.sign({ id: user.id, email: user.email }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: 30 });
};

const generateRefreshToken = (user) => {
    return jwt.sign({ id: user.id, email: user.email }, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn:60 });
};

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results.length === 0) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Utente non trovato' });

        const user = results[0];
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Password non valida' });

        const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
        const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(user);

        
        db.query('UPDATE tokens SET refresh_token = ? WHERE id_user = ?', [refreshToken, user.id], (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.status(200).json({result: true, accessToken, refreshToken });
        });
    });
});

app.post('/token', (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.body;
    if (!token) return res.sendStatus(401);

    console.log(token);

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        console.log(user);
        if (err) return res.status(403).json({ message: err.message, user: user });
        
        const accessToken = generateAccessToken({ id: user.id, email: user.email });
        res.json({ accessToken });
    });
});

const authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {

        if (err) return res.status(403).json({massage: err, user: user});
        
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
};

app.get('/protected-route', authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to protected-area', user: req.user });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

my problem is that when I give it the expired token, the service responds to me with "jwt expired".

the problem seems to come from "authenticateToken" which replies with 403.

How can I fix this error? passing the expired refresh token to refresh it I receive it

```
{
    "message": "jwt expired"
}
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: Not clear what you need. If you receives expired token is because token expired, that's how jwt works. #1 Do you want to renew the token (refresh)? #2 Do you want a long live token? #3 Do you want to change the response when token has expired?

Comment: yes! I want to renew a token (refresh)

Comment: #1 Did you read the oauth2 refresh token grant https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/  ? #2 I see you are implemented the refresh token generation and its usage. What is the error? #3 To avoid downvotes, clarify your question, focus on one problem and share a reproducible code

Comment: I don't understand because not working...

Comment: How is not working? What is the error?

Comment: error 403 but instead I expect 401

Comment: #1 Is this your error: toke expire, you get a new token using the refresh token, use the refresh token and get a 403? #2 If not make a diagram to explain your flow #3 Share a screen of your error (postman or web) #4 Can you post  a reproducible code without mysql?